# Ninject not injecting in an existing winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, ninject

I have a feeling this is just a misunderstanding on my part of DI in winforms.

I'm trying to implement [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) into an existing winforms app. In Program.cs I am doing something similar to

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectBindings());
Application.Run(kernel.Get<MainContainer>());
```

My NinjectBindings has

```
Bind<IFilterEngine>().To<FilterEngine>();
```

Then in a customer usercontrol (SearchResults.cs) in a form of the MainContainer form I am trying to use method injection like so

```
[Inject]
public void AddFilterEngine(IFilterEngine filterEngine)
{
   _filterEngine = filterEngine;
}
```

The app compiles and runs fine however, my _filterEngine instance is null and the AddFilterEngine method is never called. Is this because SearchResults is not created with Ninject? It is hardcoded in its parent form. If so, I'm assuming every parent from this point needs to also be created with Ninject?

Answer (score 1):

Injection only occurs when the instance is created through Ninject, i.e. by calling `Kernel.Get<T>()`, which is usually only done at the "topmost" point within your application or by Ninject creating this instance itself.

So unless you create your usercontrol by calling `Kernel.Get<SearchResult>()` (assuming the class is called `SearchResult`) using self-binding or by the container (as a constructor argument for example), your method will never get invoked, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use a field or a Property setter for Ninject to Inject your value on object creation.

```
[Inject]  
public IFilterEngine FilterEngine { get; set; }
```

You can also pass it as a parameter to the constructor if you don't what this property to be public. This is the preferred method. Follow the examples on the Ninject website.